# Do I have to disconnect from GoogleApiClient?

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client

Do I have to explicitly disconnect from GoogleApiClient?

Background:
I have an Android app that uses the GoogleApiClient in multiple activities. Currently as I don't want to reconnect in every activity I connect to it in an overwritten `Application` class. As the `Application` class does not have a `onDestroy` method I can't disconnect from there.

Is the GoogleApiClient connection somehow auto-closed when my app gets destroyed?

Would it be better to connect / disconnect on every activity switch? (I don't like that cause it always seems to take some time, and in my app activites are switched quite often.)